# Redirect to page with .htaccess password

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Is it possible to redirect a 'person' to a folder on a website which is protected by a passworded .htaccess.

Possibly by the use of php or otherwise, other than the "http://user:pwd@web.site" way?

Or is it best just to script your own folder/file view of these protected areas.

Comment: It's possible... not without user:pwd... has nothing to do with php.. voting to close.

Comment: why not just use sessions instead of password protecting the .htaccess? that is traditionally how it's done

Comment: Yes, thats what I'm thinking about, I use sessions for login to the page, but have some file hierarchy that is protected by htaccess. Which is why I added the last part about it perhaps being best to just script a browser for that need instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most browsers will issue warnings about the embedded username/password, as that sort of link has been traditionally abused by spammers to cloak their penis pill URLs behind "normal looking" links.

If you want to do an automatic login, redirect with an encrypted token of some sort that the protected site can decrypt and grant/deny access based on that.

In bare-bones form:

```
$raw_token = array('username' => 'joe', 'password' => '123', 'coming_from' => 'yoursite.com');
$crypted_token = base64_encode(do_some_encryption(json_encode($raw_token), 'the passphrase'));

header("Location: http://othersite.com?token=$crypted_token")
```

and then on the receiving end:

```
$crypted_token = $_GET['token'];
$raw_token = json_decode(do_some_decryption(base64_decode($crypted_token), 'the passphrase'));

$username = $raw_token['username'];
$password = $raw_token['password'];

do_login($username, $password);
```

Comment: That seems like a fair idea, but I guess that's a yes to make my own folder view, and not use htaccess.